# Lots of RUNNABLE threads in java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod0(Native Method)

Tags: java, jvm

I've been taking thread dumps of our system to troubleshoot various problems, and one thing I've noticed is that in good times and bad, we have a lot of things like this in the thread dump:

```
"TP-Processor59" - Thread t@915
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethodInfo(Class.java:929)
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1081)
    at java.lang.Class.getSimpleBinaryName(Class.java:1220)
    at java.lang.Class.getSimpleName(Class.java:1112)
```

Now, we do make a lot of calls to getSimpleName(), which our config system relies on.  But my question is why do they always get caught in this particular method?  This is a Windows JVM, 1.6.0_29, 64-bit.

I feel like getSimpleName() should in general be a very fast call.  Is this most likely getEnclosingMethod0() is somehow very slow, or is it possible that that native method is somehow blocking on something (which would, of course, not show up in the JVM thread dump)?

Comment: Can we see more of the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue with an infinite loop today. While troubleshooting the problem we saw that most often the thread stacks ended with this method call.

When we identified the problem it had nothing to do with getEnclosingMethod0 but was an infinite loop at a much higher level. Even though doing some quite costly things in the loop it seemed that the getEnclosingMethod0 call was by far the slowest thing that was done.

My conclusion is that the getEnclosingMethod0 can occasionally be very slow, even though it does not block (which it didn't do in our case AFAIK).